# Github basic issue automation

Tags: github, automation, workflow, github-projects

I want to automate issue allocation on the new Projects(beta) of Github with these conditions:

`When any issue is created, set it to "Todo" Status and StartDate to today`

`When any issue is closed, set it to "Done" Status and FinishDate to today`

I already have a "Projects" project created with these attributes:

- Status::selector = Todo, Doing, Done
- StartDate::Date
- FinishDate::Date

The basic "Projects" workflow automation only allows me to set only one action per issue creating event, but I need to do 2 actions.

And I don't know how to do that automation, being digging around other repos and the workflow marketplace but nothing seems to do this simple basic automation. How can I do that?